# mac homebrew install opencv

Tags: python, macos, opencv, homebrew

I did homebrew download opencv but something wrong.

if i try to intstall again it shows

```
Warning: opencv 4.6.0_1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 4.6.0_1, run:
  brew reinstall opencv
```

but if i check the version, it shows
➜  ~ opencv --version
zsh: command not found: opencv

I am a super begineer of it.
Please help me out :O

```
➜  ~ brew install opencv
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).

You have 1 outdated formula installed.
You can upgrade it with brew upgrade
or list it with brew outdated.

Warning: opencv 4.6.0_1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 4.6.0_1, run:
  brew reinstall opencv
➜  ~ which opencv
opencv not found
➜  ~ opencv --version
zsh: command not found: opencv
```

Answer (score 1):

The **homebrew** **OpenCV** package doesn't install a runnable program called `opencv` that you can run with:

```
opencv
```

Rather, it installs *libraries* and *packages* that you can use from Python or C++. If you want to see all the stuff it installs, you can run:

```
brew ls -v opencv
```

Any binary (executable) programs will likely be in a directory called `bin`, so you can see things that are likely to be runnable with:

```
brew ls -v opencv | grep bin
```

I don't have it installed, but I recall it used to install a program called `opencv_version` so you could see if that is there and run it with:

```
/usr/local/bin/opencv_version
```

and also try adding the `-v` option to see how it was built.

---

Another way of testing if it is installed is by trying to use it, e.g. with Python:

```
python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
4.5.4
```